Generate equation from surface
Does Blender have already a way to generate equations from simple surfaces?
In my case, I have a bowl and I want to find out the inner surface xyz equation of it. I've seen that you can do the other way around, generate mesh from equation, but in my case the equation is the unknown. I know I could code some identification algorithms, but I want to know if Blender has this option already or if there are any addons someone could guide me to.
thanks for any insight

No, Blender is not a mathematics program. It cannot "find" any equations for anything. You can enter equations and it will place vertices etc. according to the results, but it does not calculate equations based on any given arbitrary surfaces.

Unless your bowl is simplistic and follows a pattern like ax² + bx + c, I don't know if it is even possible with regular grade computers in any program. You would have to write a regression algorithm in 3 dimensions which could amount to any number of polynomials and solutions. Would you mind sharing an example of a program that would achieve what you want, even if it's private or paid for ? I'm not an expert by any means I'm genuinely wondering if this exists.

If your surfaces are always 'bowls' :  (rotations of a curve, )  then could this problem be reduced to 'equation of a curve' ?

@RobinBetts Even if, you could enter an equation in Blender to form a curve, but you cannot make a curve in Blender and let Blender find a corresponding equation - so I guess this is no BSE question. In Excel I would say, just let it determine the trendline.

Hi, @GordonBrinkmann fair enough.. curve-fitting is never going to be a Blender native activity :)   .. just wondering about very constrained cases.. e.g. known to be quadratic as suggested by Gorgious, or maybe extracting polynomial coefficients from the handles of a Bezier.. you would know better, I'm sure.

@RobinBetts Well, sure there are probably ways to determine equations by reading out control point positions and handles etc., but you would have to do it manually. And since the question says "I know I could code some identification algorithms, but I want to know if Blender has this option already" I guess ioanau is not asking for manual ways to do it yourself.

sorry, didn't receive comment notifications. Hi @Gorgious. I ended up importing the STL in matlab and using their identification toolbox, turned out to be a good fit for a 4th degree polynomial.

@RobinBetts i guess it did end up being that.  and yes indeed, maybe it's not a blender question, but was just very hopeful about the possibility.

@Gorgious AI Feynman is the example you're looking for. Beware, however: last time I tried to use it (to figure out a solution to beveling a cube) I spent like a week trying to make it work. I was so excited at the beginning and so resigned at the end I burned out for like a month :D

Thanks @Gordon Brinkmann for the answer to my question basically. I ended up importing the STL in matlab and using their identification toolbox, turned out to be a good fit for a 4th degree polynomial. Excel and other software would probably worked fine as well, I am just more familiar with Matlab.

You could [Edit] in some example to show your workflow, so that people in future can benefit from it, cheers!
